# MongoDB from MLab : find by ID not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mlab

I have been trying so hard to filter my records by **ID** from MongoDB without success. The problem is with **$oid**

On **MLAB** my records look like :

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57603891dcba0f7813102b3f"
    },
    "age": 10,
    "name": "john",
    "answer": "3",
}
```

My **script** as:

```
     mycollection.find({_id:"57603891dcba0f7813102b3f"},{},{},function(err, docs) {
    console.log("record"+docs);
    docs.each(function(err, doc) {
      if(doc) {
        console.log("record"+doc);
      }
    });
  });
```

What is wrong in it? any idea guys?

Answer (score 11):

The issue with your script is that you are trying to compare a normal string `"57603891dcba0f7813102b3f"` with a ObjectId string

```
{
        "$oid": "57603891dcba0f7813102b3f"
},
```

If you are using Node.Js, here's what you can do

1)  Import ObjectId api from mongodb package

```
 var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

2) Convert normal string to ObjectId in your query

```
mycollection.find({_id:ObjectId("57603891dcba0f7813102b3f")},{},{},function(err, docs) {...}
```

Btw, The answer posted by @titi23 also works. But i find ObjectId conversion a cleaner approach.

Comment: this works with my local mongoDb installation but not with the MLab connection. I am still having a null as return value...

Comment: Can you share the sample data from you mLab instance?

Comment: A sample document is what I have shown on the question:     {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57603891dcba0f7813102b3f"
    },
    "age": 10,
    "name": "john",
    "answer": "3",
}. Any new document inserted in mlab is being formatted with $oid.

Comment: It seems that op's oid field is not object id

Answer (score 9):

You can search on mLab in this way.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59b59b34852a9619b486634f"
    }
}
```

But your javascript code should be,

```
uId = ObjectId("59b59b34852a9619b486634f")
User.findOne({"_id": uId}, function(err, user){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :-

```
 mycollection.find({"_id.$oid":"57603891dcba0f7813102b3f"},{},{},function(err, docs) {
console.log("record"+docs);
docs.each(function(err, doc) {
  if(doc) {
    console.log("record"+doc);
  }
});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

On your local development MongoDB server, the "_id" is indexed and identified using ObjectID("....").
For example, when querying locally you may get

```
{ "_id": ObjectID("....") , "name": ".......", "password" : "............"}
```

while querying in Mlab or any remote mongodb server, the "_id" is referenced as "$oid". For example,

```
{ "_id": { "$oid": "..........."} , "name": "......."}
```

If you are like me, you may try to edit the document's "_id" in MLab and replace the former description with the latter, Mlab won't allow you to do such, i think that's part of its restrictions. Try it out and see if you have any workarounds to share.